# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource -- But it is?

Tags: apache-2.4, cors

My `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf` on a remote server looks like this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias images.example.com
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        DocumentRoot /home/username/var/www/example.com/public_html/
        ErrorLog /home/username/var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/username/var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm running a Django project on my local machine. The project makes a GET request to the remote server to read a JSON file: `http://images.remote-server.com/dir/subdir/info.json`

But I see this error in my browser's console.

```
Failed to load http://images.remote-server.com/dir/subdir/info.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I see nothing in my `error.log`.

How do I correctly set the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` in my `.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

To add the CORS authorization to the header using Apache, simply add the following line inside either the **Directory**, **Location**, **Files** or **VirtualHost** sections of your server config (usually located in a *.conf file, such as httpd.conf or apache.conf), or within a .htaccess file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
....      
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart(reload) apache

It seems that you've added "Header" to the wrong virtual host

Comment: I have that already in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf`.